# Show nothing if IS_NULL is false

Tags: php, mysql

I have the situation where I am using the below script. I only want 1 form to come up (either the first where a merchant exists in my $query, or the seconf if the merchant doesn't). The second situation currently works, however if a merchant exists in my $query, the form I have is repeating itself.

Here is the code - any help or recommendation would be amazing, and thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `merchant_profile` where merchant='$id'");

while($detail = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
  
echo "<form id='merchantProfileForm' method='POST' action='updateProfile.php?id=".$detail['merchant']."'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='displayname' placeholder='e.g.' value=".$detail['displayname']."><br><br>";
echo "<textarea placeholder='Tell us' maxlength='140' name='about'>".$detail['about']."</textarea><br><br>";
echo "<button id='addSubmitButton' type='submit' name='submit'>Update</button>";
echo "</form>";
}


$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if (is_null($row['merchant'])) {
  
echo "<form id='merchantProfileForm' method='POST' action='createProfile.php?id=".$id."'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='displayname' placeholder='e.g.' value=".$id."><br><br>";
echo "<textarea placeholder='Tell us your story' maxlength='140' name='about'></textarea><br><br>";
echo "<button id='addSubmitButton' type='submit' name=\'submit\'>Update</button>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle this, but one is you could read all the data into an array first.

```
$rows = [];
while($detail = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) $rows[] = $detail;
```

And then you can check the number of rows in $rows to see if you need to show the non existing merchant, or the results one.

```
if (count($rows) == 0) {
  // No merchant
} else {
  foreach ($rows as $detail) {
    // Display the merchant form
  }
}
```

This is just one way. And really, it looks like you're only receiving a single result in this case, so the loop isn't necessary, but it should work regardless.

On a side note, your query is susceptible to SQL injection. You are not properly filtering $id. You should be using prepared or parameterized queries.

Comment: Implemented this and working like a charm, thanks! How would I filter ID to avoid sql injection?

Comment: In your example, you should at least be checking that $id is numeric (assuming merchant is a number). So you could have something like:
if (!is_numeric($id)) exit('Invalid ID');

...but you really should look up and understand SQL injection since you can open up big holes in your applications like this. You can Google around, but here's an article:
https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

As well, it might be easier for you to use PDO instead of mysqli. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I'm new to SQL/PHP so that helps a lot

Answer (score -1):

move the first part to the `else`:

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `merchant_profile` where merchant='$id'");



$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if (is_null($row['merchant'])) {
  
   echo "<form id='merchantProfileForm' method='POST' action='createProfile.php?id=".$id."'>";
   echo "<input type='text' name='displayname' placeholder='e.g.' value=".$id."><br><br>";
   echo "<textarea placeholder='Tell us your story' maxlength='140' name='about'></textarea><br><br>";
   echo "<button id='addSubmitButton' type='submit' name=\'submit\'>Update</button>";
   echo "</form>";
} else
{
   while($detail = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
   {
  
      echo "<form id='merchantProfileForm' method='POST' action='updateProfile.php?id=".$detail['merchant']."'>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='displayname' placeholder='e.g.' value=".$detail['displayname']."><br><br>";
      echo "<textarea placeholder='Tell us' maxlength='140' name='about'>".$detail['about']."</textarea><br><br>";
      echo "<button id='addSubmitButton' type='submit' name='submit'>Update</button>";
      echo "</form>";
   }
}
?>
```